# TypeError: Expected bytes in Flask app

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to implement a simple flask app which will pass a json file to the front end, but got an error as following:

```
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2016 17:53:02] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 500 - Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/michelleshieh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 2000, in __call__
>     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "/Users/michelleshieh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1992, in wsgi_app
>     return response(environ, start_response)   File "/Users/michelleshieh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py",
> line 1228, in __call__
>     app_iter, status, headers = self.get_wsgi_response(environ)   File "/Users/michelleshieh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py",
> line 1216, in get_wsgi_response
>     headers = self.get_wsgi_headers(environ)   File "/Users/michelleshieh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py",
> line 1167, in get_wsgi_headers
>     for x in self.response)   File "/Users/michelleshieh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py",
> line 1167, in <genexpr>
>     for x in self.response)   File "/Users/michelleshieh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_compat.py",
> line 112, in to_bytes
>     raise TypeError('Expected bytes') TypeError: Expected bytes
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2016 17:53:03] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
```

The coding related to the url '/test' is:

```
@app.route("/test",methods=['GET'])

    def get_local_json():
        SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        json_url = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static/data","predict.json")
        #console.log("url is all right")
        data = json.load(open(json_url))
        return app.response_class(data, content_type='application/json')
```

And the coresponding code for front-end:

```
$.getJSON('/test', function(data){  
        var myData = [];
        for(var i in data){
            var item = data[i];
            var myItem = [];
            myItem.push(new Date(item.time).getTime());
            myItem.push(item.occupancy);
            myData.push(myItem);
        }
        console.log(myData);
```

Any hints are appreciated!!

Comment: you could try `data = json.load(open(json_url,"rb"))`

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisFabre thx, but nothing chagned.

Comment: it was a wild guess. Sorry.

Comment: You're turning the data into a dictionary when you call `json.load`; presumably data should remain bytes i.e replace `data = json.load(open...` with `data = open().read()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning a Python object other than a `bytes` object here:

```
return app.response_class(data, content_type='application/json')
```

That's not a JSON response, that's an *unencoded* Python list or dictionary.

Just return the JSON data *without* decoding it:

```
    with open(json_url, 'rb') as json_file:
        return app.response_class(json_file.read(), content_type='application/json')
```

or if you must do something with the data structure first, re-encode it back to JSON. Use the `jsonify()` utility function for that:

```
with open(json_url) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# manipulate data as needed

return jsonify(data)
```